# Python multiprocessing.pool not waiting for processes to finish?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am attempting to run sets of simulations in parallel, and after each individual set, I need to run some commands to remove certain output files that were created from the simulations. Because the second group of commands require the output file to exist (it will always be output regardless if the simulation executed properly or not), it cannot be executed until all simulations of that set are finished. For reasons I explain later, the remove commands must be executed after its own set is done, and I cannot just execute all remove commands after all simulations are finished. This is all occurring on a Linux machine running Anaconda Python 3.6.3.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import subprocess

def getCMDS(ARGS):
    # do stuff
    return allCMDs

def minions(cmd):
    subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True)
    return

def runParallel(entries):
    for i in entries:
        CMDs = getCMDS(i)
        with Pool(processes=60) as pool: # multiprocessing.cpu_count() returns 72
            for n, cmd_sets in enumerate(CMDs):
                print('Command Set {} of {} for {}'.format(n+1, len(CMDs), i))
                term_flag = False
                try:
                    pool.map(minions,cmd_sets[0]) # exeCMDs
                except KeyboardInterrupt:
                    pool.terminate()
                    pool.join()
                    term_flag = True
                    break
                for cmd in cmd_sets[1]: # removeCMDs
                    subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True)
            pool.close()
            pool.join()
        if term_flag:
            break
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C']
    runParallel(list1)
```

To help clarify, `allCMDs` is a nested list of command strings of the form:

```
allCMDs = [[exeCMDs, removeCMDs],  # for set 1
          [exeCMDs, removeCMDs],   # for set 2
          ...]  # ...
```

where `exeCMDs` and `removeCMDs` are their own lists of command strings.

What I expect to happen is:

1. All simulations associated with Set 1 pertaining to 'A' in `list1` are run to completion
2. The remove commands for Set 1 entry A are executed
3. All simulations for Set 2 entry A are run to completion
4. The remove commands for Set 2 entry A are executed
5. ... Loop through all sets, then loop through all entries from `list1`
6. Complete

While monitoring using Linux's `htop`, what actually happens is for the first couple minutes everything looks as expected, but soon I start to see simulations from Set 2 entry A alongside simulations from Set 1 entry A. Eventually this continues on and I'll see a Set 5 entry A and so on join the list. This means `pool.map()` is not waiting for its processes to finish before the script continues on. This also means the remove commands aren't actually doing anything because they execute before the file is created. This eventually leads to my machine running out of storage space as there are many simulations and these files that are meant for removal are quite large. As an added note which confuses me, I only ever see my `print('Command Set ...')` printed to the terminal the very first time. There are no errors raised from the script. I must manually stop the script using Keyboard Interrupt in order to kill everything after my storage becomes full, and delete and reset to try again.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**
I have solved my problem. I did not realize I made errors when creating `allCMDs` in `getCMDs()` which contained commands that shouldn't have been included. Below is my final working code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import subprocess

def getCMDS(ARGS):
    # do stuff
    return allCMDs

def minions(cmd):
    subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True)
    return

def runParallel(entries):
    for i in entries:
        CMDs = getCMDS(i)
        with Pool(processes=60) as pool:
            for n, cmd_sets in enumerate(CMDs):
                print('Command Set {} of {} for {}'.format(n+1, len(CMDs), i))
                term_flag = False
                try:
                    pool.map(minions,cmd_sets[0])
                except KeyboardInterrupt:
                    pool.terminate()
                    pool.join()
                    term_flag = True
                    break
                for cmd in cmd_sets[1]:
                    subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True)
        if term_flag:
            break
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C']
    runParallel(list1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not so much an answer but rather some suggestions because I can't see anything obviously wrong with the logic except for a missing colon (`:`). It is possible that you may have simplified the code to the point that you have inadvertently removed the erroneous logic. If I might, however, offer a few suggestions:

You might consider using a multithreading pool instead of a multiprocessing pool only because you worker functions are doing nothing except calling `subprocess.run`, which is in itself starting a new process. Should you also try to terminate the program by entering Ctrl-C, this will also prevent the pool processes from outputting messages (there is a solution to that also discusses later). I would also suggest that a slight re-arrangement of the code will result in your only having to create the pool once rather than repeatedly for each element of the `entries` argument. This re-arrangement can also simplify the logic:

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import subprocess


def getCMDS(ARGS):
    # do stuff
    return allCMDs

def minions(cmd):
    subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True)
    return

def runParallel(entries):
    try:
        # multiprocessing.cpu_count() returns 72
        with ThreadPool(processes=60, initializer=init_pool_processors) as pool:
            for i in entries:
                CMDs = getCMDS(i)
                for n, cmd_sets in enumerate(CMDs):
                    print('Command Set {} of {} for {}'.format(n+1, len(CMDs), i))
                    pool.map(minions, cmd_sets[0]) # exeCMDs
                    for cmd in cmd_sets[1]: # removeCMDs
                        subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True)
        # An implicit pool.terminate() call is made
        # when the with block is terminated.
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C']
    runParallel(list1)
```

If you stick with using a multiprocessing pool, then your pool processes should ignore any Ctrl-C interrupts. This can be done by defining an additional function, `init_pool_processes` and specifying it as the *inititialzer* argument to the `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` constructor:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def init_pool_processes():
    import signal
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)

...

        # multiprocessing.cpu_count() returns 72
        with Pool(processes=60, initializer=init_pool_processors) as pool:
```

Is there any reason why you do not want to multithread/multiprocess the "remove" commands?

Comment: I fixed the missing colon. I tried replacing Pool with ThreadPool; however, that seems to yield the same results: later simulations are running before the first set finishes completely. I am having difficulty implementing your suggested re-arrangement as there are complications that you are unaware of due to simplifying my code. I didn't find the need to multiprocess the "remove" commands as 1. they only take a few seconds to complete anyways and 2. why overcomplicate a simple process and cause my self more headache since I clearly don't fully understand multiprocessing.

Comment: Can you post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that **somebody other than you (such as I, for example)** can actually run that duplicates your actual problem?

Comment: I tried to create a minimal, reproducible example, but it kept working properly as intended. This made me dig a little more into my code elsewhere, and I found the culprit. Multiprocessing was working correctly, and the issue was within `getCMDs()`. I incorrectly setup `allCMDs` which led the exeCMDs for every simulation (set, entry, etc.) to be included each time which is why I was seeing sets 2, 3, etc. included with set 1. So, apologies for leading you astray since the error was not with multiprocessing. I have fixed the issue and it seems to be running correctly now.

Comment: You might then wish to update your question with this comment or even perhaps even delete the question altogether to avoid other people who do not see your latest comment to my answer form spending wasted effort on this.